# Removing single site from IE8 browser history

Tags: internet-explorer-8, history

I'm using Internet Explorer 8 and need to remove one particular site from my browser history. I want to leave the other sites still there, but just excise this single entry. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Open IE8, then do a ctrl+H

navigate to the site entry and right click on it and select "delete"

[image]